# can there be a private email activity?

Tags: activities, acl

i'm planning on creating a new activity type "private phone call" so I can use the activity acl extension to restrict access to these by user level.
Is there any way to achieve the same thing for emails?

Comment: By "emails" do you mean "sent emails" or "contact email addresses"?

Comment: "Sent emails" so the activity can have access restricted by the activity acl extension. It would mean 2 "send an email" activities - one "normal" and one with viewing restricted by the extension

Comment: CiviCRM only has one type of "Sent email" activity... but once the email is sent you could enact a little bit of hook code to change the activity type to "Private email".

Comment: Thanks Coleman would the hook apply to all sent emails or could there be a way to select, perhaps by sender. I was actually thinking civirules could achieve the same thing but I see that "change activity type" is not an available action.

Comment: A hook is custom code so yes it could select by sender or any other criteria you can write code for. And if you know enough PHP to do that, then you probably know enough to add a "change activity type" action to CiviRules, I think those actions are all pretty straightforward to write :)

Comment: Don't know any php unfortunately - I notice search kit has "change activity type" could the code be pinched from there?

Comment: If you'd like to [work with the core team](https://civicrm.org/work-with-the-core-team) we could add that feature for you, probably just a 2-3 hour project :)

Comment: I'd love that! Let me talk to my boss. What would the process be?

Comment: Sounds good. Feel free to reach out to me at coleman at civicrm.org

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help Coleman but I've found the strangely named "edit Triggering activity" which does exactly what I need.
Cheers
Lesley